# adding a picture over a picture html+css

Tags: html, css

I want to add a pin to the map I created. It should pin point some specific point on the map so that when the website is displayed on screens of different sizes the pin and map position is responsive to the screen size change.
When the pin is hovered it shows some address. I found this dropdown menu and I edited the code of it to get this pin hover effect. (But I don't know remove this list tags from it but this way it works fine) But I don't understand how I can add the pin to the map. I tried with `margin-left` and `margin-top` but when I try the responsive design mode it just doesn't work (it changes its location)

```css
 
.map {
    border-radius: 2em;
    width: 40%;

}
.pin {
    width: 5%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
  
li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
    
li {
    color: #fff;
}
  
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
ul li ul {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    left: 2.5rem;
    display: none;
}
  
ul li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"/>
</head>
<body>

        <ul>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pTCiMq9.png" class="pin">
            <ul>
              <li>address</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TtjBzLY.png" class="map">
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try positioning in terms of % position on the map rather than rem which will likely be amounts of 16px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your map have a relative position and your pin have an absolute position, then position the pin using `%` from `top` and `left`.  I would also recommend using a div layout to achieve this.  Pleas take a look at what I did here:

```css
.map {
    border-radius: 2em;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 5rem;
}
.pin {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
}

.address {
  display: none;
     color: #fff;
    float: left;
    padding: 10%;
    margin: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.pin:hover .address {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background: orange;
    min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    left: 2.5rem;
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="map"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TtjBzLY.png" class="map">
 <div class="pin"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pTCiMq9.png" class="pin">
  <div class="address">address</div>
 </div>
</div>

       
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed :) It helps a lot! :)

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would put both the map image and the pin image into the same container element (a `div`), apply `position: relative` to that div, then apply `position: absolute` to the pin img and define its position by using the `left` and `top` parameters with percentage values. Make the map image fully fill the parent div (or the other way round, defining the size of the `div` exactly as wide and high as the map image). That way the div will be the position anchor for the pin.

That way the 100% will be the full width (for the `left` setting) or height (for `top`) of the map image.

Answer (score 1):

Here I made the `position` of both images `absolute`. Additionally I gave `.map` a `z-index` behind `.pin`. Adjust the pin as you wish.

```css
.map {
    border-radius: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.pin {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
  
li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
    
li {
    color: #fff;
}
  
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
ul li ul {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    left: 2.5rem;
    display: none;
}
  
ul li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"/>
</head>
<body>

        <ul>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pTCiMq9.png" class="pin">
            <ul>
              <li>address</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TtjBzLY.png" class="map">
      
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The pin moves when you adjust the screen size.

Comment: @John I see. I agree that your answer is more efficient.